# Check if month and year appears in a list in excel

Tags: excel

I have a source cell which defines a date (01/01/2015) in cell A2. I want to check if any of the dates in the range of cells K2 to K10 are within that range of month (i.e Janurary) and year (2015).

This is the closest I could get myself:

```
=IF(MONTH(K2:K10)=A2,1,0)
```

I also tried this:

```
=IF(MONTH(K2:K10)=MONTH(A2),1,0)
```

However this gives me the error: #Value!

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: So the formula you want must return 1 if any of the dates are in the range, and 0 otherwise?

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes I just want a check to know if there are dates in that range which fall within the same month as the date in A2. Edited to show another thing I tried

Comment: Hum. The first case works for me. What's in K2 to K10, and A2?

Comment: In A2 is 01/11/2015 and in K2 is 03/11/2015 (both formatted as DD MM YY) and K3, K4, K5 are blank. Not working on my excel (2010).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly something like this:

```
=SUM(IF(MONTH(K2:K10)=MONTH(A2);1;0))
```

Needs to be an array formula (press ctrl+shift+enter)
This will return 1 or 0 depending upon the date you enter in A2.

Comment: Sorry, use , not ; - im using a different locale!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with a range, only if K2 not K2:K10

Comment: Works for me. :) Are you sure you are using a formula array with the function?

Comment: Oh...thank you this works now, I forgot formular array!

Comment: How do I make it factor in the year though? As in, make it so the year has to the be the same too? Sorry to be a pain

Comment: Probably something like: =SUM(IF(MONTH(D3:D14)=MONTH(F3);IF(YEAR(D3:D14)=YEAR(F3);1;0))) with commas obviously.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is due to the "blank" cells actually being empty strings.

A trick is to use IFERROR:

`=SUM(IF(IFERROR(MONTH(K2:K10*1),0)=MONTH(A2),1,0)>0,1,0)`

The `*1` will fail for a blank string which, in turn, will fail the subsequent comparison.

Note that this is a single-cell *array* formula. Use Ctrl + Shift + Return to enter it.

Answer (score 1):

[Office support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MONTH-function-579a2881-199b-48b2-ab90-ddba0eba86e8) states:

> The MONTH function syntax has the following arguments:
>
> ```
> Serial_number   Required. The date of the month you are trying to find.
> ```
>
> Dates should be entered by using the DATE function, or as
>   results of other formulas or functions. For example, use
>   DATE(2008,5,23) for the 23rd day of May, 2008. Problems can occur if
>   dates are entered as text.

How are you entering date? if you enter them by hand you need to parse the date with something like [this excel formula](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-month-name-from-date)

Comment: I'm entering as 01/01/2015 and formatting it as date (DD MM YY)